# Cannot execute explode with array_map

Tags: php

I'm trying to execute `explode` over an `array` to remove an apostrophe `'` from a specific field called `minute`, the array have this structure:

```
[
   {
    "id": "15888",
    "round_id": "488",
    "home_team_id": "95",
    "away_team_id": "104",
    "team_id": "95",
    "player_marker_id": "68165",
    "player_assist_id": "319468",
    "match_id": "2564737",
    "minute": "8'",
    "result": "1 - 0",
    "type": "1"
   },
```

Below is my code:

```
  $goals = $sql->fetchAll(); //Take data from table

  //replace the field removing the '
  $goals = array_map(function($x) use($a)
    {
      return [$a[0], $x];
    }, explode("'", $a[1]["minute"]));

return $goals;
```

I get:

```
[
    [
        null,
        ""
    ]
]
```

what I did wrong?

Comment: what is $a? why did you explode $a[1]['minute'] to append it with $a[0]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :** (an alternative to remove `'`)

```
$json ='[{"id": "15888","round_id": "488","home_team_id": "95","away_team_id": "104","team_id": "95","player_marker_id": "68165","player_assist_id": "319468","match_id": "2564737","minute": "8\'","result": "1 - 0","type": "1"}]';
$goals = json_decode($json);
foreach ($goals as $key => $item) 
{
    $item->minute = rtrim($item->minute,"'");
    $data[$key] = $item;
}

print_r($data);
```

See the demo : https://eval.in/1027187

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 15888
            [round_id] => 488
            [home_team_id] => 95
            [away_team_id] => 104
            [team_id] => 95
            [player_marker_id] => 68165
            [player_assist_id] => 319468
            [match_id] => 2564737
            [minute] => 8
            [result] => 1 - 0
            [type] => 1
        )

)
```